# Making a docker container a part of a vpn

Tags: docker

I am trying to connect my docker container to a vpn in order to access the machines in that vpn. I wonder how could this be done.

I can connect the host machine (machine on which docker container is hosted) to the vpn using the vpn client provided by the cloud provider.

The same vpn client does not work on the docker container. Can someone please help me in finding out the way to get the docker container to become a part of the vpn.

The vpn server is publicly accessible. I need the docker container to become a part of the VPN just like how the machine hosting the docker container can become a part of the vpn.

I have multiple docker containers on my host machine and each container should be a part of a separate vpn. Can this be achieved anyway?

Answer (score 1):

[Kontena](http://www.kontena.io) has [built-in VPN access](http://www.kontena.io/docs/using-kontena/vpn-access), so if you want an easy solution I suggest you to check it out

Comment: how is the Kontena project doing? Built-in vpn is great stuff. I noticed that there's only 12 search results at stackoverflow for "kontena" though, while I cannot get Kontena to work at all, so I wonder how that could be.

Comment: Project is doing great, though not many questions has been asked here. The main support channel has been Kontena Community Slack channel: https://slack.kontena.io/. So feel free to join if you have any troubles.

Of course I'm happy to tag your question with #kontena tag here as well.

Comment: Ok tnx I did. So how does that work? Searching for `URL not specified and current master not selected` returns `no message results`. Same for `master not selected`.