# Is it possible to run a VPN client inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, virtualization

Is it possible to run a VPN client inside a docker container?

And if it is, then will it be possible to communicate between the host and the container?

An example of the architecture -

`Host     <->           Container            <->       VPN
172.0.0.1        172.0.0.3 & 222.104.0.105      222.106.3.5`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related (but takes a different approach of having the container orchestration provide the VPN to the docker container ): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097726/making-a-docker-container-a-part-of-a-vpn?rq=1

Comment: I'm not looking for a product. I'm looking for an answer to my question.

Comment: It's not really important in your case but, 222.106.3.405 isn't an IP address ;)

Comment: hahaha thanks for the notice @AntoninM.

Answer (score 2):

Configuration example of such scenario can be found here: https://greenfrognest.com/LMDSVPN.php

It is based on a specific VPN docker container client (dperson/openvpn-client), but as far I can see it can be configured using any VPN provider.

Associated YouTube video with above instructions can be found [here](https://youtu.be/fBaq22GMjEQ)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30303600)

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to run openvpn or such a container, you will find many in the docker hub, look at http://registry.hub.docker.com and if you `docker run --net=host` it will communicate with the host